# Free SMTP server for Windows Server 2008?

Tags: windows, windows-server, smtp

I am looking for SMTP server software. I would like to add an SMTP server to my machine running Windows Server 2008 R2.

Note that Windows has a built in feature I could turn on. The problem is that it needs IIS running for it to work. I do not have IIS installed on the server, as I have Apache 2.4 running instead.

What software can I use to turn SMTP server on my Windows machine?

Answer (score 1):

You could give [Shicks!](http://p-nand-q.com/download/shicks.html) a go:

- [Python](http://python.org) Based
- Free Gratis & Open Source
- Fully RFC-compliant POP3/SMTP server for small network
- BSD Licenced
- Web based administration / remote access
- Includes spam detection: Keyword detection, DNSBL (DNS-based blacklists for spammers), regular expression filtering.
- Runs on Linux and Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I would check out [hMailServer](https://www.hmailserver.com/). It not only add's SMTP support, but it also if wanted can support IMAP and POP3 protocols too.

> hMailServer is a free, open source, e-mail server for Microsoft
>   Windows. It's used by Internet service providers, companies,
>   governments, schools and enthusiasts in all parts of the world.
>
> It supports the common e-mail protocols (IMAP, SMTP and POP3) and can
>   easily be integrated with many existing web mail systems. It has
>   flexible score-based spam protection and can attach to your virus
>   scanner to scan all incoming and outgoing email.

There is also [mailEnable Standard Edition](http://www.mailenable.com/standard_edition.asp) too,

> **Standard Edition - Unlimited Domains/Users MailEnable Standard Edition**
>   provides robust SMTP, IMAP, POP3 and Webmail services for Microsoft
>   Windows servers. Simple to install, with powerful administration
>   software means that your mail server will be up and running quickly.
>   This edition is free, contains no spyware or adware, for both personal
>   and commercial usage, with no time or user restrictions.